# English term for switching phonemes between words?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there the English term for switching phonemes between words, creating something like Freudian mistakes?

For example, changing 'lumberjack' to 'jumper's luck'.

As fair as I can remember, one of Gummi Bears from children's TV series was permanently using such constructions.

Comment: The question seems to be asked in a better way here than in the earlier 'duplicate'. Perhaps the two could be merged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are talking about a [spoonerism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism), and it was used frequently by Zummi of the Gummi Bears childrens TV show.

Lumberjack to Jumper's Luck isn't a great example though, a more traditional example of a spoonerism would not change the b to a p.

Comment: "Three cheers for our queer old dean!" and "The Lord is a shoving leopard." I think Rev. Spooner might have been having fun.

Comment: "Punk in Drublic" o_O

Answer (score 0):

How about **parapraxis**

Check out:
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parapraxis

"a minor error in action, such as slips of the tongue, supposedly the result of repressed impulses "

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parapraxis

"a slip of the tongue or pen, forgetfulness, misplacement of objects, or other error thought to reveal unconscious wishes or attitudes. "

Origin:
para- + Greek  prâxis  act, action; cf. praxis